# Amazon S3 + Fog warning: connecting to the matching region will be more performant

Tags: amazon-s3, fog

I get the following warning while querying Amazon S3 via the Fog gem:

```
[WARNING] fog: followed redirect to my-bucket.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com, connecting to the matching region will be more performant
```

How exactly do I "connect to the matching region"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the :region option in the Fog connection parameters to the name of the region in which your bucket exists.

For example, I have a bucket called "bucket-a" in region "eu-west-1" and my s3 key and secret are in variables s3_key and s3_secret respectively.

I can connect to this region directly by opening my Fog connection as follows:

```
s3 = Fog::Storage.new(provider: 'AWS', aws_access_key_id: s3_key, aws_secret_access_key: s3_secret, region: 'eu-west-1')
```

And now when I list the contents, no region warning is issued:

```
s3.directories.get('bucket-a').files
```

If you want to do this for all your buckets, rather than on a bucket-by-bucket basis you can set the following:

```
Fog::Storage::AWS::DEFAULT_REGION = 'eu-west-1'
```

Comment: I am using [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) gem with s3adapter in a rails 3.2 app. [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) uses fog internally. Despite of adding `region: 'ap-southeast-1'` parameter to the hash, I continue to get the warning @clozach has mentioned

Comment: what version of sitemap_generator are you using?

Comment: sitemap_generator-4.1.0. The hash key is called `fog_region`, which ultimately gets passed on to fog as `region`.                                                             `{aws_access_key_id: <aws_key>,                                                            aws_secret_access_key: <aws_secret>, 
fog_provider: 'AWS', 
fog_directory: <bucket_name>, 
fog_region: 'ap-southeast-1'}`

Comment: Use 
`Fog::Storage::AWS.send(:remove_const, 'DEFAULT_REGION')
Fog::Storage::AWS::DEFAULT_REGION = 'eu-west-1'`
To avoid the warning.