# S3 + Fog redirection error with eu-west-1 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fog

I am using **Rails 4** and **assets_sync** (which uses **Fog**) to use **Amazon S3** for my assets. The S3 bucket is on "**eu-west-1**" (Ireland).

In **production.rb** and **development.rb** environments I have set up the following line (being BUCKETNAME the real bucket name):

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME"
```

Also, I have set up the next environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, FOG_DIRECTORY, FOG_PROVIDER (and also FOG_REGION=eu-west-1 in a desperate attempt).

No matters what I do, I get the following error (which is already [posted in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659691/amazon-s3-fog-warning-connecting-to-the-matching-region-will-be-more-performa%20here) which an answer that does not help me)

```
rake assets:precompile
[WARNING] fog: followed redirect to BUCKETNAME.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com, connecting to the matching region will be more performant
[WARNING] fog: followed redirect to BUCKETNAME.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com, connecting to the matching region will be more performant
rake aborted!
Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
(... more trace details ...)
```

Despite of this error, assets are sometimes uploaded (as *application-7d888bd5c98564a528d102954bf2061a.css*), which anyway does work because application is linking assets this way:

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If it helps, I have the following options enabled in production:
    config.assets.compile = false
    config.assets.digest = true

Any suggestion that could help me to approximate to a solution?

Comment: Seems that I had not _config.assets.digest = true_ active in development enviroment. Zone warnings continue appearing but everything works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure the Fog S3 endpoint:

**If you use Heroku:**

```
heroku config:add FOG_REGION=eu-west-1
```

**If you use a custom Rails initializer (config/initializers/asset_sync.rb):**

```
AssetSync.configure do |config|
    config.fog_region = 'eu-west-1'
```

For additional details see:

https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync#built-in-initializer-environment-variables

As for the `asset_host` configuration, I think your current setup should work but the [assets_sync readme](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync#rails) has the following note:

> **On non default S3 bucket region:** If your bucket is set to a region
>   that is not the default US Standard (us-east-1) you must use the first
>   style of url //#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com or amazon will
>   return a 301 permanently moved when assets are requested. Note the
>   caveat above about bucket names and periods.

So if you do see any 301 redirects when requesting the assets, try:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, dcro. I was establishing the FOG_REGION locally using env vars. Also, I tried the asset host that you referenced and it wasn't working (because of other issue) so I changed it to the one that AWS uses to link files. I have voted your answer as correct as all that you have said is true and can help anyone in the same situation as me.