# Trying to set up Amazon's S3 bucket: 403 Forbidden error & setting permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, railstutorial.org

I'm following Hartl's railstutorial.org and have arrived at [11.4.4: Image upload in production](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#sec-image_upload_in_production). What I've done:

- Signed up for Amazon Web Services
- In Amazon Identity and Access Management I created a user. The user was created succesfully.
- In Amazon S3 I created a new bucket.
- Set permissions on the new bucket:

**Permissions:**
The tutorial instructs to "grant read and write permission to the user created in the previous step". However, under 'Permissons' for the bucket the new user's name is not mentioned. I could only choose between Everyone, Authenticated users, Log delivery, Me, and a username Amazon seems to have created itself from my name + a number. I have tried it by selecting Authenticated users and checked the boxes for Upload/Delete and View permissions (and not selecting List and Edit permissions). I also tried it by selecting Everyone and checked all the four boxes. The results were the same.

- I implemented in my Rails application following the instructions of the tutorial (I don't belief anything wen't wrong there, so I haven't included those steps here to not make it too long).

The initializer `carrier_wave.rb` is set to the code below. I've added `region: 'eu-west-1'` to the initializer (an idea I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659691)) to get rid of the message `connecting to the matching region will be more performant`.

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      # Configuration for Amazon S3
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],           # Set these key's using heroku config:set S3_ACCESS_KEY=<access key>
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
      :region                => 'eu-west-1'
    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

- It worked in development and I pushed to Heroku.

**Error:**
When using the uploader in production to upload an image, I get the error `We're sorry, but something went wrong.` The Heroku server log says:

```
app[web.1]:   SQL (1.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "avatar" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["avatar", "animaatjes.png.gif"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-20 12:37:56.683858"], ["id", 18]]
heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/18" host=xxx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx-7f9f-4580-89ba-xxx fwd="xx.xxx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3461ms status=500 bytes=1714
app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3317ms (ActiveRecord: 13.0ms)
app[web.1]:    (1.4ms)  ROLLBACK
app[web.1]: Excon::Errors::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
app[web.1]: excon.error.response
app[web.1]:   :body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>F8xxxD89</RequestId><HostId>MdB5iSMgxxx1vqE+Q=</HostId></Error>"
app[web.1]:   :headers       => {
app[web.1]:     "Connection"       => "close"
app[web.1]:     "Content-Type"     => "application/xml"
app[web.1]:     "Date"             => "Wed, 20 May 2015 12:37:57 GMT"
app[web.1]:     "Server"           => "AmazonS3"
app[web.1]:     "x-amz-id-2"       => "MdB5iSMg***K1vqdP+E+Q="
app[web.1]:     "x-amz-request-id" => "F80A**C58"
app[web.1]:   }
app[web.1]:   :local_address => "***.**.**.**"
app[web.1]:   :local_port    => *****
app[web.1]:   :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
app[web.1]:   :remote_ip     => "**.***.***.***"
app[web.1]:   :status        => 403
app[web.1]:   :status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:46:in 'update'
app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6151ms (ActiveRecord: 60.7ms)
```

What have I done wrong? I seems to have something to do with the permissions?

---

**Update:**
The cause turned out to be the policies granted to the user. If I grant the user standard AmazonS3FullAccess then it works. It doesn't work with just AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess, since then the user can't save a new image. In my application the user basically only needs 2 rights: upload its own avatar image and read the avatar image. **Would it be safe to use AmazonS3FullAccess or should I write my own custom policy?**

I tried the custom policy below, which should give the application read and write rights (adopted from [here](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3VRSWZ6B3SHAV/Writing-IAM-Policies-How-to-grant-access-to-an-Amazon-S3-bucket)) but that still generated the `403 Forbidden` error.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How does this relate to the error in your title? I think you'll need to write either a bucket policy or an IAM policy granting access to your user - see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html

Comment: Thanks, I changed the title. The thing is I'm following the steps of railstutorial.org. I think it should be pretty straightforward. Therefore, I'm a bit hesitant whether any customization should be necessary. Wouldn't normally a user created in IAM be available to grant permissions to for a bucket? So, might that not be what's going wrong?

Comment: The tutorial doesn't tell you how to grant access at all - it just says "read the docs".

Comment: I guess that's true. I only see two standard policies for S3: AmazonS3FullAccess and AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess. Having added the (key) credentials of the user in the Rails application, I gave the user AmazonS3FullAccess and than it indeed worked. With only AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess the user can't upload it's avatar image (only read it). The user basically only needs 2 rights: upload its own avatar image and read the avatar image. Do you think I should (somehow) write my own custom policy or is it safe to use AmazonS3FullAccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem indeed turned out to be the permissions. It was necessary to write a custom policy and set the CORS configuration on the bucket. For any future users that want to implement this chapter of the rails tutorial, see [Writing an IAM policy and CORS configuration for Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358220/writing-an-iam-policy-and-cors-configuration-for-amazon-s3) for the necessary code.

Answer (score 6):

To enable S3 file Uploads, I had to:

- specify my region (us-west)
- create an IAM user
- add a Bucket Policy specifying that user as a Principal

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowFileUpload",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:user/instaswan"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::instaswan-dev",
                "arn:aws:s3:::instaswan-dev/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Be sure to include both the top-level and "/*" Resource, and include any other "Action" attributes you need.

Comment: Thanks for tip on top-level. I had to do that, then was able to get Excon not to puke up. Adding the `Principle` was not valid and allowed in the policy for S3.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `s3:PutObjectAcl` was the permission that was missing

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing a step which is to set your IAM policy if using an IAM user to configure your bucket.

Go to IAM console, select your user, go to the `permissions tab`, click the `attach policy` button and add `administrator access`.

After that the error should go away and you can upload files with no problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Tried many solutions including S3@FullAccess, creating users, writing custom policies. If someone encounters the problem, then check bucket permissions. Go to bucketname > Permissions > Public Access Settings, then change two ACLs settings from True to False.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the thing is Amazon changed their layout so now creating a user policy is a bit different than before. So once you create a policy remember to attach the policy to the user in question or you will get the 403 forbidden error

Answer (score 0):

I had both the issues from the tutorial -

Look in your heroku logs -

Forbidden

and

Socket Error

Going round trying to resolve this over a day I basically reset back to basics, Recreated a new IAM user and a new s3 bucket but this time left the REGION as US standard - the only s3 authority I could find to attach as the policy was full access - nothing else - so attached that

Also retyping and confirming ENV variables on heroku as well as COPY AND PASTING the carrier_wave.rb from tutorial - to be sure to be sure .)

first time round I was fiddling and unsure what to do so i might of clicked a few different things- adding groups and permissions, viewing wrong things - sometimes a RESET and STEP through everything especially after exploring AWS and IMS and s3 for the first time.

Interesting that in heroku they INSTRUCT to set the bucket region as US standard and post a warning - Be sure to create a bucket in the same region as your app to take advantage of AWS’s free in-region data transfer rates.

good read for heroku to s3 configuration here ->
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3